# Unwanted autofill in formular

Tags: jsf, firefox, jsf-2, primefaces

Not sure if this is a Firefox or Primefaces issue.

i have a simple form with

- name
- email      -> 'test'
- password1  -> '****'
- password2

When i enter the page, email and password1 are filled with the word 'test'.
I have deleted all my history and formular data, but it is still there.
The formular is not filled if i use private browsing or IE.
When i switch the order of outputLabel and inputText to

- email
- name       -> 'test'
- password1  -> '****'
- password2

than name and password1 are filled with the word 'test'.

```
<p:outputLabel value="Name" for="name" />
<p:inputText id="name" value="#{registration.user.name}" />
<p:outputLabel value="Email" for="regEmail" />
<p:inputText id="regEmail" value="#{registration.user.email}"/>                        
<p:outputLabel value="Password 1" for="pwd" />
<p:password id="pwd" value="#{registration.password}" match="pwd2" 
label="Password 1" required="true"/>                
<p:outputLabel value="Password 2" for="pwd2" />
<p:password id="pwd2" value="#{registration.password2}" 
label="Password 2" required="true"/>
```

Any idea, how i can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `autoComplete="false"` on the component and hope your browser respects it

```
  <p:password id="pwd" value="#{registration.password}" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" autoComplete="false" required="true"/>
```

Comment: i have set autocomplete="false" but the values are still there.

Comment: @tak3shi "hope your browser respects it"... you might need to clear your browser cache and try it again